# How do you stop a thread and flush its registers into the stack?

Tags: c++, multithreading, memory-management, concurrency, garbage-collection

I'm creating a concurrent memory reclamation algorithm in C++. Periodically, the stacks of executing mutator threads need to be inspected, so that I can see what references the threads are currently holding. In the process of doing this, I need to also check the registers of the mutator thread to check any references that might be in there.

Clearly many JVM's and C# vm's have no problem doing this as part of their garbage collection cycles. However, I haven't been able to find a definitive solution to this issue.

I can't quite tease apart what is going on in the Bohem garbage collector in order to inspect the root set, if you can (or know how its done), I'd really like to know.

Ideally I would be able to cause the mutator thread to be interrupted, and execute a piece of handler code which would report it's PC and also flush any register-based references into the stack, and then perhaps help finish the collection cycle. I believe that most compilers in most systems will automatically flush the registers when interrupt or signal handlers are called, but I'm not clear on the specifics, or how to access that data. It seems that separate stacks might be used for interrupt and signal handlers. Additionally, I can't find any information about how to target a particular thread, or how to send a signal. Windows does not seem to support this form of signaling anyway, and I would like my system to run on both Linux and Windows on x86-64 processors.

*Edit:* SuspendThread() is used in some situations, although safepoints seem to be preferred. Any ideas on why? Is there any way to deal with long-lasting I/O waits or other waits for kernel code to return?

Comment: No flushing is used, the collector simply checks the registers for object references.  Easy to do in Windows with GetThreadContext().

Comment: Well, `GetThreadContext` doesn't read registers at all.  It reads the memory the registers were saved to the last time a context switch inactivated that particular thread.

Comment: @coolkid: Compilers don't flush registers when interrupts occur (nor do they emit code to do so), that's a feature of the CPU itself.

Comment: I don't think flushing registers to the stack will work from outside the thread (without @josh-haberman's safepoints), because the compiler can use a register for a variable, without allocating any stack space for it. Instead, you should get the register values and check them as well as the stack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thought this was a very interesting question, so I dug into it a bit.  It turns out that the Hotspot JVM uses a mechanism called "safepoints" which cause the threads of the JVM to cooperatively all stop themselves so that the GC can begin.  In other words, the thread initiating GC doesn't forcibly stop the other threads, the other threads voluntarily suspend themselves by various clever mechanisms.

I don't believe the JVM scans registers, because a safepoint is defined such that all roots are known (I presume this means in memory).

For more information see:

- [HotSpot Glossary](http://openjdk.java.net/groups/hotspot/docs/HotSpotGlossary.html) -- which defines safepoints
- [safepoint.cpp](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/hotspot/hotspot/file/9b0ca45cd756/src/share/vm/runtime/safepoint.cpp) -- the source in HotSpot that implements safepoints
- [A slide deck](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/picasso/mats/HotspotOverview.pdf) that describes safepoints in some detail (look 10 slides or so in)

In regards to your desire to "interrupt" all threads, according to the slide deck I referenced above, thread suspension is "unreliable on Solaris and Linux, e.g., spurious signals."  I'm not sure what mechanism even exists for thread suspension that the slides would be referring to.

Comment: Hmm.. If this is the case, then how do you deal with the fact that a thread might not get scheduled for some time if it is waiting for IO or the OS simply has many competing processes? I would hate to have to stall for that.

Comment: If you check out the link to safepoint.cpp above, the comments say that any threads that are currently blocked will not be allowed to continue until the safepoint operation is complete (so it's like they're already at a safepoint).  I'm guessing that all runnable threads have to get scheduled before the GC can begin so they can pause in a known state, probably no way around that.

Comment: Yikes! That could be a long time if one of them is waiting for IO or is sleeping waiting for a lock to be released. Anyone know for sure if this is really the case?

Comment: [This post](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/sasha/archive/2009/07/31/garbage-collection-thread-suspension-delay-250ms-multiples.aspx) about .NET's GC talks about .NET trying to use safepoints for about 1s, and then giving up and using a SuspendThread() call. Very interesting.

Comment: For threads waiting for I/O, I don't think you have to wait for them to get scheduled.  They are put into a "safe" state *before* blocking for I/O, so you can start GC while they are blocked (they are prevented from continuing if the I/O completes while the GC is active).

Comment: Thanks for all the great responses!

Answer (score 1):

On windows you should be able to get this done use [SuspendThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686345%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (and ResumeThread) along with [GetThreadContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679362%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (as Hans mentioned). All of these functions take handles to the specific thread you intend to target.

To get a list of all threads in the current process, see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686852%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)(toolhlp32 works on x64, despite its bad naming scheme...).

As a point of interest, one way to flush registers to the stack on x86 is to use the `PUSHAD` assembly instruction.

Comment: The "usual" way to flush registers to the stack is via interrupt.

Comment: @BenVoigt: afaiak windows doesn't provide that outside of kernel mode (I could be wrong).

Comment: That's the traditional way of accessing kernel services from user-mode, is with a software interrupt.  x86 now has the `sysenter` instruction, which streamlines things somewhat, but I believe it still performs the same register saving.  But really, I was just commenting on your statement that `PUSHAD` is the only way to save registers to the stack, since it isn't.  BTW, context switches are caused by interrupts (either I/O or timer) and that's how the thread state ends up in memory for `GetThreadContext` to access.

Comment: @BenVoigt: fixed my text up then.

Comment: So, to use GetThreadContext, what has to happen to the thread I am inspecting? Does it have to sleep itself first, or can I just call GetThreadContext on it and it will interrupt the thread and store the registers?

Comment: @coolkid: `You cannot get a valid context for a running thread. Use the SuspendThread function to suspend the thread before calling GetThreadContext.`

Comment: @Necrolis: Will SuspendThread work if the thread is waiting for (say) disk I/O, or waiting to be scheduled? [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686345%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says "Suspending a thread causes the thread to stop executing user-mode (application) code. This function is primarily designed for use by debuggers. It is not intended to be used for thread synchronization.". This makes me think that (1) it might not stop threads that are waiting for system calls to return, and (2) that it might not be very fast. Any experience with this?

Comment: [This interesting post](http://www.dcl.hpi.uni-potsdam.de/research/WRK/2009/01/what-does-suspendthread-really-do/) has some information, if you're interested in SuspendThread().